# How to display two activity on same screen

Tags: android

I want to display two screen (One main and another at bottom). Following is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.seekbar);



    showBottomScreen();

}

private void showBottomScreen() {

    setContentView(R.layout.bottom_layout);
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.bottom_layout);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.leftMargin = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    params.rightMargin = (int)TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 10, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    layout.addView(new bottomProvider(this).generateInLineView(),params);
}
```

Problem is that now i am able to see bottom screen not main screen. Please give some suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

**What is happening now:**
Using `setContentView()` twice only sets the content of the activity to whichever is set the last.

So:
 `setContentView(R.layout.seekbar);`  and after that

```
setContentView(R.layout.bottom_layout);
```

*Just sets the `bottom_layout.xml` as the content view of your activity.*

**What you want:**
There are alternatives to achieve what you want, depending on your requirement.

A *simple* way of doing it:
You can try including all elements of your screen as one, in either `seekbar.xml` or `bottom_layout.xml`
If working your way with various [layouts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html) - relative, linear, frame and a scrollview.

**Or**

Go for the multi-pane UI and related development by using [Fragments in Android app](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html),
for reference:
 1. [Multi-pane development in Android with Fragments](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFragments/article.html)
 2. [Android Fragments Example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/app/fragment/android-fragments-example/)
 3. [Imp read:How to use Fragments? and its Life cycle](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_fragments.htm)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are [fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).